# Can different networks connected by MPLS run the same OSPF area?

Tags: gre, ospf, mpls

I was wondering if two different OSPF areas connected via an MPLS/GRE tunneled link run OSPF across them?
May be keeping the interconnecting MPLS/GRE routers in OSPF backbone area 0?

Comment: I know I can use OSPF virtual links which are tunneled to connect an disconnected OSPF area to backbone network. But was wondering about the specific use case where I connect two disconnected networks via a tunnel into a single OSPF area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly run OSPF on GRE interfaces and routers will exchange routes quite happily via the GRE tunnel.  A GRE interface should be just like any other interface to OSPF, so normal rules would apply for area assignments just the same as they would apply to other interface types.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the OSPF "Sham-Link" feature. This feature builds virtual OSPF links over an MPLS infrastructure to connect OSPF networks. The feature is available on [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_ospf/configuration/15-sy/iro-15-sy-book/iro-sham-link.html) and [Juniper](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.3/topics/topic-map/ospfv2-sham-links.html) gear at least.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is commonly done over metro Ethernet circuits via an L2VPN solution (ie pseudo-wire or VLL) or can also be done with L3VPN services from a carrier - but this means that you need to participate in routing with your carrier - more often than not however this will require more complexity in your L3 domain; so rather than doing this, it is possible to run OSPF over a GRE tunnel, as @JeffMcAdams has mentioned. It's usually more desirable to utilize an L2VPN-based solution.